# Can we ask our Manage package provider to enable 'Do not allow duplicate value' checkbox under all objects' fields for our org?

Tags: salesforce, unique

[image]
**Challenge**- We have a managed package provider ERP that currently locks us from editing the checkbox 'Do not allow duplicate value' (as in the attached screenshot).

**Question/objective**:

1. Can a Manage package's provider exclude this from enforcing it as a managed package's part? In other words, can they unlock this checkbox in all the fields' field definition per object? Is it technically possible for them?
2. Can somebody share the steps they will need to take to make this happen for our Org? :)

Any input will be equally valuable for us!

Thanks in advance!

Couldn't find any solution yet